# CMake error - cmTryCompileExec has stopped working (VTK)

Tags: c++, cmake, vtk, itk

Hello I am trying to compile VTK and ITK with CMake under Windows 8. ITK compiled perfectly, but when I try to deal with VTK by CMake I get error `cmTryCompileExec has stopped working`. How can I solve this problem? My version of CMake is 2.8.12.1

Comment: I think there is more to this error message

Comment: the compiler its calling could be crashing.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the script which is running the try-compile test is crashing. Solution: [Update VTK](http://vtk.1045678.n5.nabble.com/cmTryCompileExec-has-stopped-working-CMake-GUI-td5727059.html).